# Why multilingual site url is not working in production site?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have multilingual site such as `www.demo.com` and `bn.demo.com` it works fine at dev and local site. but when i deployed at production it's url language is not working.

When I hit www.demo.com it goes english site. and then when i hit bn.demo.com it should come at bangla site but the strings are not translated.

Surprisingly when I logged in then switch url the translated string works fine. Why it does not works at logged out situation? how can I resolve it?

And my .htaccess files and rewrite condition

```
# (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|bn)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is `Cache pages for anonymous users` enabled on `https://example.com/admin/config/development/performance`? It might be that the cached pages for anonymous users are not yet aware of the language. A cache clear should solve that.

Comment: It's enabled and Cleared cache but not solved

Comment: Then it might be related to load balancers and/or Varnish cache? Without knowing your infrastructure it is hard do tell, but because it works when you are logged in, it is likely cache related.

Answer (score 0):

Just a beginner's suggestion... when you migrate your site, did you turn off clean URLs, clear cache and put into maintenance mode before migrating?  If not, I suggest you try that then turn back on clean URLs, and take out of maintenance mode.